# Inverse of Lightning tab onactive?

Tags: tab

There is a lightning input element in the body of a tab of my custom standalone app and I would like to have any values in the input element cleared once I move to another tab or any other part of the application. Since there is only an ***onactive*** but no ***"inactive"*** attribute for a tab, is there a workaround for achieving this? Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `lightning:tabset` then you can try to use` onselect` method of the tabset. Here you can apply your logic in case of tab switch.

Comment: I actually tried doing this as well but in the case where I have tabsets nested within other tabsets and the tab of interest is in the innermost nest, I will have to use multiple `onselect` methods and attributes to accomplish the task. I was hoping that there was a way of working on just the one tab of interest but if there is no workaround, I guess I will have to do it the long way.